# how to convert a one row input into multiple lines in the shell

Tags: shell, unix

I'm using a shell script that contains a 1 row input for multiple IP's

script input:

```
./part1.sh 10.10.11 10.10.12 10.10.13
```

in the shell script:

```
export Master="$1 $2 $3"

the output is -- >10.10.11 10.10.12 10.10.13
```

i want to use it in the script as

> 10.10.11
>
> 10.10.12
>
> 10.10.13

how can we convert this inside the script ?

Comment: why do you want to have multiple lines? you can save them in array `arr=($1 $2 $3)` , pls tell you ultimate goal. If you said `i want to use it in the script as...`  it sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: You can also note that "if "you want to use "all" the arguments then you can use `$@` to capture all arguments.

Comment: the script will run using Jenkins , thats why the inputs are supposed to be in 1 line , but in the script itself i need them to be converted to multiple lines ... so i can use them one by one i was thinking of using export Master="$1/n $2/n $3/n" but its not working good

Comment: To achieve what you have asked, you should be using: `master=$(echo $1 $2 $3|tr " " "\n")` or `echo $master|tr " " "\n"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example using bash:

```
$ cat foo.sh
#!/bin/bash

declare -a ips=( "$@" )

for ip in "${ips[@]}"
do
  echo $ip
done
```

Run it:

```
$ bash foo.sh 10.10.11 10.10.12 10.10.13
10.10.11
10.10.12
10.10.13
```